# bash: check if multiple files in a directory contain strings from a list

Tags: linux, string, bash, text, grep

Folks,

I have a text file which contains multiple lines with one string per line :

```
str1
str2
str3
```

etc..

I would like to read every line of this file and then search for those strings inside multiple files located  in a different directory.

I am not quite sure how to proceed.

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: You want to identify which files (located in another directory) contain any of these strings?

Comment: Not sure if this most community spirited approach, but I edited things to clarify the question along those lines. My take on the OP's question may be incorrect though. Bluz, if my edits capture the intent of your original question I hope that's ok. If not I apologize.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity in my question.What I was looking for is a command that reads each line of the pattern file, then lookup that string in every file from $directory and returns both the $Filename and the $StringMatch value when there is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} { for (word in a) if ($0 ~ word) print FILENAME, $0 }' fileOfWords /wherever/dir/*
```

Answer (score 2):

### Use the GNU Grep's `--file` Option

According to grep(1):

```
   -f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain  patterns  from  FILE,  one  per  line.   The  empty file
          contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.   (-f  is
          specified by POSIX.)
```

The `-H` and `-n` flags will print the filename and line number of each match. So, assuming you store your patterns in /tmp/foo and want to search all files in /tmp/bar, you could use something like:

```
# Find regular files with GNU find and grep them all using a pattern
# file.
find /etc -type f -exec grep -Hnf /tmp/foo {} +
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, I didn't know that grep option. This didn't return anything but I think it's because my question wasn't clear enough in the first place. Thanks for the grep tip though ! :)

Comment: @Bluz I've updated the answer to return the filename and line number, and to fix a small syntax error. If you have GNU grep, it should work for you now. Good luck!

Comment: Outstanding! Exactly what I needed! And the line number is the icing on the cake. Thanks very much :D

Answer (score 2):

```
for wrd in $(cut -d, -f1 < testfile.txt); do grep $wrd dir/files* ; done
```

Comment: I did a for wrd in $(cut -d, -f1 < checks.txt); do grep -o $wrd hosts/*; done instead and it worked just fine :) thanks ! (looks like I can't format code in this comment box?)

Answer (score 1):

```
while read -r str
do
   echo "$str"
   grep "$str" /path/to/other/files
done < inputfile
```

Comment: Can fail in many different ways thanks to missing setting of IFS, -r argument for read, and quotes around variables.

Comment: Also you should add a caveat that it will only work on some shells in some boxes due to the non-portability of `echo`.

Comment: This should work fine in Linux. OP has his question with Linux as one label.